# Cannot renew jobject in JNI

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

My application is an Android app with some native code.

The Java code starts a thread via new Thread(new Runnable), in the native code, I attach that thread to the JVM via AttachCurrentThread.

The native function which is called in that thread is an endless loop which will listen for simple events(boolean variables) and call another native function which by using the proper JNIEnv pointer and jobject will fill 2 java variables on the Java side and call a void method to display the data. The reason for that loop is that the overhead to calling the function normally(has a lot of allocation and destruction to do) is most likely huge.

The only problem is that while I can renew a JNIEnv pointer, I have no idea how to do it for a jobject.

And by jobject I mean the jobject which is passed to the native code via the function call like so

```
jint Java_com_example_example_MainActivity_NativeFunc( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject obj)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you intend to keep a reference to an object in native code, you need to explicitly keep a reference (and presumably later release it) by creating a new global reference or new weak global reference.  In the latter case, you'll need to also check for equivalence to null before using it.

Comment: If you mean something else by "renew", then please explain, since AFAIK "renew" isn't standard parlance in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Java code starts a thread via new Thread(new Runnable), in the native code, I attach that thread to the JVM via AttachCurrentThread.

You don't have to attach the JVM to a thread that was created with Java code, it is already attached.

If I understood your question correctly you get a `jobject` once and want to access that object later in other native methods. To accomplish that, you can use [NewGlobalRef](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#NewGlobalRef):

```
jobject myGlobalReference = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
```

You can store that `jobject` in a global C/C++ variable and use it later. It will stay valid until the JVM dies or you delete the reference with [DeleteGlobalRef](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#DeleteGlobalRef). Keep in mind that **the garbage collection won't collect** the referenced object if all Java references to it are gone as long as you don't delete your global reference!